# sync contacts with ubuntu touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I recently installed Ubuntu Touch using MultiRom (recently being today). I was notified to sync my contacts upon opening either the dialer or the contacts app, but I brushed it aside to get back to what I was doing. Now I would like to sync those contacts and I cannot find anyway to re-gain access to that sync message. Any help would be much appreciated!